# Why is NSPredicateEditor automatically localizing some Expression strings? How to disable?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nspredicateeditor, nspredicateeditorrow, nsruleeditor

I'm finding that *some* `NSPredicateEditor` / `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate` values are being localized automatically by OS X.

This is easily observable in the mapping of operators: `.equalTo` to the string `is`.

But I just noticed that UTI strings are being mapped to a human-readable version of that UTI.

Below, I set `"public.image"` but it is then displayed as `"image"`.

[image: UTI operators in NSPredicateEditor]

```
func setupPredicateEditor() {
    let left = [NSExpression(forKeyPath: "Type")]

    let operators = [NSComparisonPredicate.Operator.equalTo.rawValue as NSNumber]

    let right = [
        NSExpression(forConstantValue: "public.image"),
        NSExpression(forConstantValue: "public.text"),
        NSExpression(forConstantValue: "public.fakeUTI"),
        ];

    let rowTemplate = NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate.init(leftExpressions: left, rightExpressions: right, modifier: .all, operators: operators, options: 0)
    predicateEditor.rowTemplates = [rowTemplate]

    predicateEditor.addRow(self)
}
```

Only certain valid UTIs are mapped in this manner. I do not know if other formats beyond Operators and UTIs are given automatic localized strings.

This is an issue because I want to [localize my NSPredicateEditor and Row Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749717/nspredicateeditor-nsexpression-can-the-display-be-different-than-the-value-f).

The process for localizing the predicate involves matching a key to a localized value.

```
KEY: "%[left]@ %[is]@ %[right]@"
VAL: "%1$[left_display_string]@ %2$[is]@ %3$[right_display_string]@"
```

The problem is that the values in the key must match the strings *shown in the UI*. Not the strings originally set to the Row Template's left and right expressions.

So, I cannot localize using `"public.image"` in the key. The UI is for some reason *already* localizing this to `"image"`. If I want to localize the Row Template, I must use the string `"image"` instead. And I don't know how or why this `"image"` string is being picked.

I could determine these strings via testing, then write a table that maps the expression to the localized string. But I'd prefer to have a solution that disables this automatic localization so that I don't have to worry about strings I have not tested.

Why are UTIs being localized automatically? Do other values receive the same treatment?

Is there a way to disable the automatic localization of the UTI strings and/or the entire predicate editor?

Comment: I've opened rdar://30468110 for Apple to add these private translation dictionaries to the public API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer but some info: `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate` translates the strings in `_displayValueForConstantValue:`. It uses a dictionary:

```
{
    "com.apple.application" = application;
    "com.apple.pict" = PICT;
    "com.apple.protected-mpeg-4-audio" = "purchased music";
    "com.apple.rtfd" = RTFD;
    "com.compuserve.gif" = GIF;
    "com.microsoft.bmp" = BMP;
    "public.audio" = music;
    "public.folder" = folder;
    "public.html" = HTML;
    "public.image" = image;
    "public.jpeg" = JPEG;
    "public.jpeg-2000" = "JPEG 2000";
    "public.mp3" = MP3;
    "public.mpeg-4-audio" = "MPEG4 audio";
    "public.png" = PNG;
    "public.rtf" = RTF;
    "public.source-code" = "source code";
    "public.text" = text;
    "public.tiff" = TIFF;
    "public.xml" = XML;
}
```

bt:

```
AppKit`-[NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate _displayValueForConstantValue:] + 913
AppKit`-[NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate _viewFromExpressions:] + 589
AppKit`-[NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate initWithLeftExpressions:rightExpressions:modifier:operators:options:] + 205
```

Edit:

`_displayValueForKeyPath:` uses this dictionary:

```
{
    kMDItemContentCreationDate = Created;
    kMDItemContentModificationDate = "Last modified";
    kMDItemContentTypeTree = "File type";
    kMDItemDisplayName = "File display name";
    kMDItemFSContentChangeDate = "Change date";
    kMDItemFSCreationDate = "Creation date";
    kMDItemFSName = "File name";
    kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID = "Owner group id";
    kMDItemFSOwnerUserID = "Owner user ID";
    kMDItemFSSize = "File size";
    kMDItemLastUsedDate = "Last opened";
    kMDItemPath = "File path";
}
```

`_displayValueForPredicateOperator:` and `_displayValueForCompoundPredicateType:` translate the enums to strings.

This should be documented but it isn't. I put a breakpoint on `_displayValueForConstantValue:` and I watched what happened. The dictionaries are hard coded and can be different in others versions of macOS.

Comment: Wow, this is great. Thank you. Is the source for this available somewhere? Are those *all* of the entries in the display value dictionary? Any idea where the `.equalTo`-to-`"is"` translation happens?

Comment: Looks like they'll be the methods `_displayValueForPredicateOperator:`, `_displayValueForCompoundPredicateType:`, `_displayValueForConstantValue:`, `_displayValueForKeyPath:`... any tips on where to find the implmentation or keys/values?

Comment: I'm hitting the breakpoint I added for `_displayValueForConstantValue:`. But can you explain how you then found the complete dictionary being used? I don't understand how that would be surfaced in the debugger. Thank you!

Comment: After `objc_msgSend` with selector `initWithObjectsAndKeys:` the returned result is in rax. `po $rax` prints the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the private API methods directly to use the system's mapping.

In Swift this requires a bridging header:

```
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate ()

- (NSString *)_displayValueForKeyPath:(CFStringRef)keyPath;
- (NSString *)_displayValueForConstantValue:(CFStringRef)constantValue;
- (NSString *)_displayValueForCompoundPredicateType:(NSCompoundPredicateType)compoundPredicateType;
- (NSString *)_displayValueForPredicateOperator:(NSPredicateOperatorType)predicateOperator;

@end
```

These private methods can then be called like so:

```
let keyPath = rowTemplate._displayValue(forKeyPath: kMDItemFSSize) // "File size"
let constantValue = rowTemplate._displayValue(forConstantValue: "com.apple.application" as CFString) // "application"
let compoundPredicateType = rowTemplate._displayValue(for: .or) // "Any"
```

The three above work, but I'm currently having issues with `_displayValueForPredicateOperator:` crashing with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` or returning the wrong string translation.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding Willeke's great answer:

Add symbolic breakpoints to the following private methods to see the mappings.

- `_displayValueForKeyPath:`
- `_displayValueForConstantValue:`
- `_displayValueForCompoundPredicateType:`
- `_displayValueForPredicateOperator:`

When you breaks, put breakpoint on a line containing `objc_msgSend` and break again there.

Then input `po $rax` to print the mapping table.

In the lower two cases it does not use a dictionary, but the strings can be seen when the breakpoints are hit.

#### _displayValueForKeyPath:

```
{
    kMDItemContentCreationDate = Created;
    kMDItemContentModificationDate = "Last modified";
    kMDItemContentTypeTree = "File type";
    kMDItemDisplayName = "File display name";
    kMDItemFSContentChangeDate = "Change date";
    kMDItemFSCreationDate = "Creation date";
    kMDItemFSName = "File name";
    kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID = "Owner group id";
    kMDItemFSOwnerUserID = "Owner user ID";
    kMDItemFSSize = "File size";
    kMDItemLastUsedDate = "Last opened";
    kMDItemPath = "File path";
}
```

#### _displayValueForConstantValue:

```
{
    "com.apple.application" = application;
    "com.apple.pict" = PICT;
    "com.apple.protected-mpeg-4-audio" = "purchased music";
    "com.apple.rtfd" = RTFD;
    "com.compuserve.gif" = GIF;
    "com.microsoft.bmp" = BMP;
    "public.audio" = music;
    "public.folder" = folder;
    "public.html" = HTML;
    "public.image" = image;
    "public.jpeg" = JPEG;
    "public.jpeg-2000" = "JPEG 2000";
    "public.mp3" = MP3;
    "public.mpeg-4-audio" = "MPEG4 audio";
    "public.png" = PNG;
    "public.rtf" = RTF;
    "public.source-code" = "source code";
    "public.text" = text;
    "public.tiff" = TIFF;
    "public.xml" = XML;
}
```

#### _displayValueForCompoundPredicateType:

```
0x7fff32a7342c <+20>: leaq   0x5ca25255(%rip), %rax    ; @"Any"
0x7fff32a73434 <+28>: leaq   0x5c9c8dad(%rip), %rax    ; @"None"
0x7fff32a7343c <+36>: leaq   0x5ca00ac5(%rip), %rax    ; @"All"
0x7fff32a73456 <+62>: leaq   0x5ca2524b(%rip), %rdx    ; @"(unknown compound type %ld)"
```

#### _displayValueForPredicateOperator:

```
0x7fff32a7331b <+42>:  leaq   0x5ca251c6(%rip), %rax    ; @"is less than"
0x7fff32a73332 <+65>:  leaq   0x5ca251cf(%rip), %rax    ; @"is less than or equal to"
0x7fff32a7334a <+89>:  leaq   0x5ca252f7(%rip), %rax    ; @"between"
0x7fff32a73356 <+101>: leaq   0x5ca251cb(%rip), %rax    ; @"is greater than"
0x7fff32a73362 <+113>: leaq   0x5ca251df(%rip), %rax    ; @"is greater than or equal to"
0x7fff32a7336b <+122>: leaq   0x5ca251f6(%rip), %rax    ; @"is"
0x7fff32a73374 <+131>: leaq   0x5ca2520d(%rip), %rax    ; @"is not"
0x7fff32a7337d <+140>: leaq   0x5ca25224(%rip), %rax    ; @"matches"
0x7fff32a73386 <+149>: leaq   0x5ca2523b(%rip), %rax    ; @"is like"
0x7fff32a7338f <+158>: leaq   0x5ca25252(%rip), %rax    ; @"begins with"
0x7fff32a73398 <+167>: leaq   0x5ca25269(%rip), %rax    ; @"ends with"
0x7fff32a733a1 <+176>: leaq   0x5ca01300(%rip), %rax    ; @"in"
0x7fff32a733aa <+185>: leaq   0x5ca25277(%rip), %rax    ; @"contains"
0x7fff32a733d4 <+227>: leaq   0x5ca2528d(%rip), %rdx    ; @"(unknown predicate operator %ld)"
```